# What's the meaning of"barraging"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> The campaign is barraging superdelegates in the South with requests
>   for support. -NY Times

What's the meaning of "barraging" in this sentence?

I searched it in the dictionary('If you are barraged by people or things, you have to deal with a great number of people or things you would rather avoid.') but its meaning is still unclear to me.

Comment: See [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/barrage), referring the definition of the verb (#5) to noun definition #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is military metaphor.  The definition of "barrage" as a noun is: ["a concentrated artillery bombardment over a wide area"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20barrage).

Indeed, it is more often used in its noun form, though there's nothing wrong with the example sentence.  But I'd expect to see a rewrite such as the following more often:

**Superdelegates in the South were inundated by a barrage of support requests.**